# #include <math.h> in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, math.h

This is a program I wrote :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"


int main ()
{
    int phi;
    float c;
    scanf_s("%d",&phi);
    c=(pow(sin(phi)*cos(phi),-2))-(pow(tan(phi),2)+pow(tan(phi),-2));
    if (c==2)
    {
        printf("C is 2,Don't Worry \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Be Careful,C is not 2,How is this possible ?! \n");
    }
}
```

The problem is Visual Studio won't recognize **sin**,**cos**,**tan** and **pow**.
what am I doing wrong ?
(as you see, the language is C!)

Comment: As a side note, your program will likely not work due to floating point precision. (The result won't be exactly 2).

Comment: Please copy/paste the error you are getting, so wee too can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Despite that you haven't pointed out error message, most probable answer is that you need to explicitely tell your compiler, that you want to treat your code as C source file instead of C++ one. Visual Studio does not have project template for C console application "as is", but you may add source file manually. Just make sure that it has `.c` extension instead of `.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are actually compiling this as a C++ file as it should compile fine as a C file. You didn't specify the exact error message but in VS 2010 I get the error:

> error C2668: 'sin' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

This is because your argument `phi` is an `int` and the compiler doesn't know which version of `sin()` to use. You can fix this by casting the integer to the desired type like:

```
int phi;
c = sin((float) phi);
```

or, simply change the type of `phi` to a `float` or a `double`.

Comment: There is no "function overloading" in C.

Comment: True, as a C file the poster's code should compile fine. I was guessing that it was being compiled as a C++ file (answer updated to reflect that).

Comment: Yup, just added answer on that too.